# Make matplotlib button widget actuate when pressed, not when released

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I made a simple interactive matplotlib figure that uses buttons to browse plots. A minimal example of one such button is:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.widgets import Button

def message(_):
    print('Hello, World!')

buttonAxes = plt.axes([0.48, 0.48, 0.08, 0.08])
button = Button(buttonAxes, 'Button', color='#FFFFFF', hovercolor='#808080')
button.on_clicked(message)
plt.show()
```

This button behaves as intended, but actuates when the mouse button is released, and not when it is pressed. If I click on the button and don't release the mouse button, `message` is never called and nothing is printed to output. This makes buttons very jarring to use in cases like mine.

How do I make buttons like these actuate when pressed? Alternatively, how do I build a replacement button that does?

Python 3.8.1 on Windows 10.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use the "button_press_event" event through the [`connect_event()`](http://connect_event) method:

```py
button.connect_event("button_press_event", message)
```